# How I can convert Rows to Columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:
    Phones

```
  ------------------------------------------------------
   | CustomerID           | PhoneID      | PhoneNum     |
   -----------------------------------------------------
   | 1                    | 101          | 09811111     |
   | 1                    | 102          | 09822222     |
   | 1                    | 103          | 09833333     |
   | 2                    | 104          | 09844444     |
   | 2                    | 105          | 09855555     |
   -------------------------------------------------
```

I want query that give me bellow result:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| CustomerID           | PhoneNum1    |   PhoneNum2    |   PhoneNum3      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1                    | 09811111     |   09822222     |   09833333       |
| 2                    | 09844444     |   09855555     |     NULL         |           
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I build the result?

Comment: You're looking to PIVOT data example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Comment: What if there are more than 3 phone numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can handle this requirement with the help of `ROW_NUMBER` and a pivot query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY PhoneID) rn
    FROM Phones
)

SELECT
    CustomerID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN PhoneNum END) AS PhoneNum1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN PhoneNum END) AS PhoneNum2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN PhoneNum END) AS PhoneNum3
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    CustomerID
ORDER BY
    CustomerID;
```

### Demo

Comment: Thank you very much. Another question, Do I can inner join this query to another table?

Comment: @AliMoosavi Yes, this should be possible, but you would probably do that join inside the CTE.  In any case, if you have another query in mind you might want to open a new question.

Comment: If I want join this cte with Customer table include CustomerID,Name,Family and ... , how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
The query above was very useful. But when I use the Where, the result is not right


WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY PhoneID) rn
    FROM Phones
)

SELECT
    CustomerID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN PhoneNum END) AS PhoneNum1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN PhoneNum END) AS PhoneNum2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN PhoneNum END) AS PhoneNum3
FROM cte
where PhoneNum ='09811111'
GROUP BY
    CustomerID
ORDER BY
    CustomerID;

Result:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| CustomerID           | PhoneNum1    |   PhoneNum2    |   PhoneNum3      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1                    | 09811111     |   NULL         |   NULL           |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I find a way for my asked

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY PhoneID) rn
    FROM Phones
)

SELECT
    CustomerID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN PhoneNum END) AS PhoneNum1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN PhoneNum END) AS PhoneNum2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN PhoneNum END) AS PhoneNum3
FROM cte
where CustomerID = ( select CustomerID from cte where PhoneNum ='09811111' )
GROUP BY
    CustomerID
ORDER BY
    CustomerID;
```